# Can we migrate PL/SQL files from VSS--> TFS?

Tags: tfs, migration, visual-sourcesafe

I am trying to migrate some PL/SQL code from VSS to TFS. Can this be done? Is there any restriction on the file type?

Comment: What do you want to migrate. VSS and TFS are just source controls. And there is already a migration tool... What you are asking depends more on you programming environment... what are you using?

Comment: Why would there be? What issues are you having, specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can migrate repositories from VSS to TFS using the `VSSConverter.exe` tool (see [this walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181247(v=vs.90).aspx) in MSDN for the complete details).

The file types are irrelevant, and the procedure should work in the same way for any file type.

Comment: Thanks!! that helps.